# Getting Facebook Recommendations with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can we get Facebook [Recommendations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/) with FQL?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FQL documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), it doesn't look like the table is exposed to retrieve any information from.

Answer (score 0):

A "recommendation" is the same as a "like", just use FQL to get the "likes".